# How to turn on the scaling in a triple Venn diagram?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to build the following diagram but while it must be possible (see the picture), I have an error about the negative area.

I also need my diagram scaled.

[image]

```
grid.newpage()                                        # Move to new plotting page
draw.triple.venn(area1 = 153,                          # Different color for each set
                 area2 = 173,
                 area3 = 224,
                 n12 = 2,
                 n23 = 26,
                 n13 = 8,
                 n123 = 140,
                 col = "red",
                 fill = c("pink", "green", "orange"), scaled = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the diagram to be scaled so that all the areas are (approximately) proportional to the number each contains, you should use the `eulerr` package instead. Note that in your example, the overlap between the three areas is so large that it is barely recognizable as a Venn Diagram any more:

```
library(eulerr)

plot(euler(c(
       "a" = 3, "b" = 5, "c" = 50,
       "a&b" = 2, "a&c" = 8, "b&c" = 26,
       "a&b&c" = 140
   )), quantities = TRUE,
   fills = scales::alpha(c("pink", "green", "orange"), 0.3))
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to get rid of labels (a, b, and c)? Thanks!

Comment: @Lara try `labels = FALSE` inside the `plot` command

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your areas are correctly summed in the arguments like this:

```r
library(VennDiagram)
grid.newpage()                                        # Move to new plotting page
draw.triple.venn(area1 = 153,                          # Different color for each set
                 area2 = 173,
                 area3 = 224,
                 n12 = 142,
                 n23 = 166,
                 n13 = 148,
                 n123 = 140,
                 col = "red",
                 fill = c("pink", "green", "orange"), scaled = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
#> (polygon[GRID.polygon.1], polygon[GRID.polygon.2], polygon[GRID.polygon.3], polygon[GRID.polygon.4], polygon[GRID.polygon.5], polygon[GRID.polygon.6], text[GRID.text.7], text[GRID.text.8], text[GRID.text.9], text[GRID.text.10], text[GRID.text.11], text[GRID.text.12], text[GRID.text.13], text[GRID.text.14], text[GRID.text.15], text[GRID.text.16])
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but these circles still aren't scaled...